# Reply to user's message from group using telegram bot pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, api, bots, telegram

So, I'm creating bot for support. it works very simple: user sends message to bot, bot sends it to private group. In private group there are guys from support. They just should reply on forwarded message

So, I've done first part - forward message from bot to group. How can I do reply to this message in my private group and forward it back using the pytelegrambotapi library?

Here you can see how message goes to private group

```
@bot.channel_post_handler(content_types = ['text'])#citySupportName
def process_step2(message):
    bot.forward_message(0000000000, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Operator is here!")
```

Comment: I tried bot.copy_message, tried forward message, reply_to, but nothing helped. Or I got "bot can't send message to bot"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add chat types like that:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"], chat_types=["private", "group"])
```